# how to tell rails to use jquery development

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a noob and am starting a new rails 3 application (3.0.7)

I will be using jquery and have read this on github:

**javascript_include_tag(:defaults) call. While the plugin downloads minified and un-minified versions of jQuery and jQuery UI, only the minified versions are included in :default.**

I have read on SO that in development its better to use uncompressed jquery and in production to use compressed.

How to I get Rails to use the un-minified version of jquery for production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to define the `javascript_expansions` differently in `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`.

For example, in `development.rb` you could have this:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions = { :default => [:jquery] }
```

and in `production.rb`, this:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions = { :default => ["jquery.min"] }
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan that is exactly what I needed to know.